# How to capitalise first word in a String, and manipulate the last word based on word's length in a given string

Tags: java, regex, string, capitalize

> Suppose String given is " this is a book ".

Condition:
**to Change for every letter in the string as Capital letter and if the words per string defined to be more than 3 letter, replace the 4th letter as with "." dot, making the dot concatenated at last representing 3 dots**

Here,

Output will be

> Thi... Is A Boo...

Program I tried, but could not replace the last character as dot with three dots.

```
public class Tip2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String testString = "this is a book";
        String[] tokens = testString.split("\\s");

        for (String token : tokens) {
            str.append(Character.toUpperCase(token.charAt(0))).append(token.substring(1)).append(" ");
        }
        str.toString().trim();
System.out.println(str);
```

How can I count and concatenate as such? Is there any way how we can check on this?

Comment: HINT:  `if (token.length() == 4)...`

Comment: I think token will not come. Any more hint

Comment: @KevinAnderson has the correct hint for you. Before appending your Uppercase token to the StringBuilder, first check if the token is actually of length 4. And if so, replace the last character with the three dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given below is how you can do it in a single statement:

```
Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s+"))
                .map(s -> s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                        + (s.length() > 3 ? (s.substring(1, 3) + s.substring(3).replaceAll(".", ".")) : s.substring(1)))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Explanation:**

1. [Arrays.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(T%5B%5D))
2. [String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))
3. `\\s+` is a regex pattern which specifies one or more space(s). Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to learn more about regex patterns
4. [Stream#map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function))
5. [String#substring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)). Note that it has two variants.
6. [String#replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))
7. `.` as a regex pattern specifies each character.
8. [Stream#forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer))

## Demo:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "this is a booking";
        Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s+"))
                .map(s -> s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                        + (s.length() > 3 ? (s.substring(1, 3) + s.substring(3).replaceAll(".", ".")) : s.substring(1)))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Thi.
Is
A
Boo....
```

If you want to create a single string, [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) the stream into a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) and [join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...)) the elements using `" "` as the delimiter.

## Demo:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "this is a booking";
        String result = String.join(" ",
                Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s+")).map(s -> s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                        + (s.length() > 3 ? (s.substring(1, 3) + s.substring(3).replaceAll(".", ".")) : s.substring(1)))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Thi. Is A Boo....
```

**[Update]** [Courtesy Rez D'Souza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62513239/how-to-capitalise-first-word-in-a-string-and-manipulate-the-last-word-based-on/62515681#comment110563442_62515681).

It can be further optimized by using `.collect(Collectors.joining(" ")))` instead of [collecting to `List` by using `.collect(Collectors.toList())` and then joining the elements of the `List` by using `String.join`].

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "this is a booking";
        String result = Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s+"))
                .map(s -> s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                        + (s.length() > 3 ? (s.substring(1, 3) + s.substring(3).replaceAll(".", ".")) : s.substring(1)))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, collect(Collectors.toList()) how this adds to list and why only this? 
Here, `.collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));` can be used to fetch same result.

Also, why `//s+` , as in the trail, there is no further whitespace, why is the need of this?

Comment: Thanks, @RezD'Souza for the kind words.

Comment: `why \\s+` - For just in case there are more than one space characters between the words.

Comment: I got it, okies, but what is the relevance of using `collect(Collectors.toList())` and not 
  `collect(Collectors.joining(" ")))` ?

Comment: It's a good suggestion. I've added your suggestion as an update.

Comment: Although I also added it's answer which is below, but this suits better, Upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Kevin, you can check the length and append `.`,

```
for (String token : tokens) {
    String subString = token.length() == 4 ? token.substring(1, token.length()-1)+"..." : token.substring(1);
    str.append(Character.toUpperCase(token.charAt(0))).append(subString).append(" ");
}
```

Comment: This answer is way too crammed to be a useful explanation. Also: it should be `token.length()-1` to produce the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (String token : tokens){
    token = token.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + token.substring(1);
    if (token.length() > 3){
        token = token.substring(0, 3) + "...";
    }
    str.append(token).append(" ");
}
```

So here it converts each first letter to uppercase, then checks length and manipulate if it is bigger than 3, and finally append them in `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I also changed it via Streams to have in one way of method :

```
    try{
                Stream.of(testString.split(" ")).forEach(s -> {
                    if (s.length() > 3) {
    
                        System.out.print(s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase().concat(s.substring(1,3).concat("...")+" "));
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.print(s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase().concat(s.substring(1,s.length()))+" ");
                    }
                });
            }catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
               

 ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the code as below

```
for (String token : tokens) {
        if(token.length() > 3) {
            token = token.replace(token.substring(3),"...");
        }
        
 str.append(Character.toUpperCase(token.charAt(0))).append(token.substring(1)).append(" ");
    }
    str.toString().trim();
    System.out.println(str);
```